# Sendgrid error 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, attachment, sendgrid, bad-request

I'm getting this error message when trying to send a email through SendGrid:

```
400 { "errors": [ { "message": "Bad Request", "field": null, "help": null } ] } array(14) { [0]=> string(25) "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request " [1]=> string(14) "Server: nginx " [2]=> string(36) "Date: Sat, 11 Mar 2017 19:20:44 GMT " [3]=> string(31) "Content-Type: application/json " [4]=> string(19) "Content-Length: 63 " [5]=> string(23) "Connection: keep-alive " [6]=> string(22) "X-Frame-Options: DENY " [7]=> string(58) "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io " [8]=> string(35) "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST " [9]=> string(87) "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl " [10]=> string(28) "Access-Control-Max-Age: 600 " [11]=> string(75) "X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html " [12]=> string(1) " " [13]=> string(0) "" }
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php

// If you are using Composer
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use SendGrid\Mail;

$apiKey = 'mykey';
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
$email = new SendGrid\Email("Me", "mail@gmail.com");

$mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
$mail->setFrom($email);
$mail->setSubject("Attachment Test");
$p = new \SendGrid\Personalization();
$p->addTo($email);
$c = new \SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "Hi");
$mail->addPersonalization($p);
$mail->addContent($c);

$att1 = new \SendGrid\Attachment();
$att1->setContent( file_get_contents("favicon.ico") );
$att1->setType("text/plain");
$att1->setFilename("1.txt");
$att1->setDisposition("attachment");
$mail->addAttachment( $att1 );

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);

echo $response->statusCode() . "\n";
echo json_encode( json_decode($response->body()), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "\n";
var_dump($response->headers());
?>
```

Not sure if it's related to the attachment. I managed to send an email using a different code, but I'm trying to implement attachments to it so this is the new code. I don't know much php so I'm kinda lost on what does this error means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you're getting is due to the attachment.

The contents of the file must be `base64` encoded. Otherwise it will malform the JSON since you're introducing random bytes into the request body.

You can see that in the complete example of the mail helper for `sendgrid-php`, a `base64` string is set as content to the attachment.
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.php#L83

As you can see in the `Attachment` class, the content is simply just set and will serialize as a string in the JSON object when the class is serialized:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/lib/helpers/mail/Mail.php#L670

You just need to use this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

To change the line:

`$att1->setContent( file_get_contents("favicon.ico") );`

To:

`$att1->setContent( base64_encode( file_get_contents("favicon.ico") ) );`

The v3 Mail Send documentation is here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html

If you scroll down to the "attachments" object and expand the "content" field, it'll show the requirements for it, maily: `The Base64 encoded content of the attachment.`